# Better way to get div to extend across the page?

Tags: html, css

I have an html page with a header across the top here is the sum total of the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<css link here>
</head>


<body onload="prettyPrint()">
<div class="header">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
body
{
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 50px; 
}
/* */
.header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(8, 36, 86); 
    color: white;
    height: 2em; 
    padding: .5em;  
    z-index: 1000; 
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: times, serif; 
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin-left: -9999px;*/
}
```

but whenever I run this, the header doesn't extend across the page and there's a small patch that doesn't appear in either chrome or firefox like so:

[image]

I've modified the css so that the header tag has a width of 1000% and a left margin of -9999px, but it feels like a hack - is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's often margin/padding in the body tag... try setting the margin-left to 0 on the body tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `html` and `body` elements often have margins and paddings set to non-zero values. Make sure your `html` and `body` has

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length): `vw, vh, vmin, vmax` and [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
.body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  z-index: 0;
  margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: Note the support of this for older browsers is limited - http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 2):

Use this `css` property for whatever element you want to be as wide as the page:

```
width: 100%
```

Answer (score 1):

browser's have a default value for their tags, for example, body have a margin:8px in my firefox browser, so you have to remove it by explicitly define it.

So its seems necessary to have a reset css for yourself, and in there put all the default value you want, to have a unique result in different browsers.

frameworks such as bootstrap have it inside them.

```
body
{
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    z-index: 0;
    margin:0;
}
/* */
.header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(8, 36, 86); 
    color: white;
    height: 2em; 
    padding: .5em;  
    font-family: times, serif; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has a default margin and padding, so the first thing to do when writing a css is to set all element to `0`

`*{padding:0; 
   margin:0;}`